# IS there any way to find what commands we have run in linux apart from history

Tags: linux

IS there any way to find what commands we have run in linux server apart from history command

is there any log file where i can see what are commands i have run

unfortunately my ~/.bash_history is clear

Comment: Time reading the first block of a command to see f it is in cache.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698590/how-to-capture-all-the-commands-typed-in-unix-linux-by-any-user and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698590/how-to-capture-all-the-commands-typed-in-unix-linux-by-any-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux distributions and installations I encountered: no, it's not possible. Even `.bash_history` is storing *only* bash history (and some administrators can (and will) use other shell(s)) and has usually set a limit so sometimes gets truncated. You would have to write and configure such utility yourself.

Comment: I will go with you I tried all possibility no log file is having the history of commands which we ran on Linux machine so once we clear history all the data is gone, there is no way to recover